# The exactly same code gets completely different Tensorboard results on different devices

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tensorboard

I have the **exactly same** code to create TFRecord file and train my model (using GPU) on two computer separately.

**1 About Hardware:**

One is my MacBook, with an NVIDIA **GTX1080** eGPU, tf1.6. The other is an Ubuntu 16 Server with NVIDIA **M4000**, tf1.6,

**2 About Code:**

I use

> tf.set_random_seed(FLAGS.seed)

and

> np.random.seed(FLAGS.seed)

and

> FLAGS.seed = 1

wherever I need to use a random function.

> I don't have any code about device

**3 TensorBoard Output:**

macbook:
[image]

Ubuntu Server:
[image]

**the accuracy and mIOU of val Almost Unchanged**

**4 Other Attempts**

1. I change my loss function, but the problem remains.
2. I upgrade my tensorflow in Ubuntu to tf1.10,but the problem remains.

**5 My Guess**

M4000 support 64-bits computation, but 1080 only support 32-bits, maybe the reason is related to this?

**6 My Question**

What is the reason of this problem and how can I repair it??

Comment: I don't have a solution but technically TF should run in 32bit so that the difference in 32/64 bit should not be noticable. Have you upgraded all drivers on the Ubuntu system? Are you using cuDNN?

Comment: yes, I remember both my MacBook and Ubuntu use CUDA9 and cuDNN7, I install tensorflow both on them at the same time several months ago.

Comment: Can I force a GPU to train a model using 32bits mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible reason for my question.

Because of my dataset feature is complicated, After I post this question, I have seen the tensorboard curves like 'Ubuntu Server' in my question several times, but after some epoch, 'acc' and 'mIOU' curve looks like the result of 'macbook'.

**So I guess there exist some hardware-related functions in cuDNN which lead to subtle differences.**